# Why svn merge result is arbitrary?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Why and How to solve it?
Win7 x64 and the newest TortoiseSVN installed on my machine.

We're in some crunch time now,
and have trunk and branch like many others.

I had to commit to trunk, and merge it to branch many times today,
because lots of bugs I made.

Anyway! Merge result not reliable!
I had no problems before.

First I tried external diff & merge tool, Beyond Compare from Scooter Software.
It seems better than before, but I still get a random result.

Help me, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge one than one time in sequence **the same sources** (merged data not changed between runs) you'll get **the same results**. Period

> I had to commit to trunk, and merge it to branch many times today, becuase lots of bugs I made...

If you "commit-merge-commit-merge...-commit merge" you have changed at least one source, merge-result **will differ** in this case. What's so surprising to you?

Anyway

> merge result is not reliable!

is not good description of problem, even not description of problem at all. Stop hysterics and show as much details, as you can. Something like this (I'll try just imagine your case)

### Sample Bug Report BEGIN

When I try to merge `URL/trunk/filename@REVA` with `URL/branches/somebranch/filename@REVB` I always get different merge  results, see

`SAMPLEMERGED1`

`SAMPLEMERGED2`

`SAMPLEMERGED3`

even with the same diff all times

`svn diff URL/trunk/filename@REVA URL/branches/somebranch/filename@REVB`

`... diff output here ...`

History of branch file is

`svn log --stop-on-copy URL/branches/somebranch/filename@REVB`

`... log output here ...`

I have TortoiseSVN v. NNN and repository on SVN-server v. NNN

### Sample Bug Report END